# Jenkinsfile one type of parameter instead of two type, convert choice into string or string into choice

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm using two parameters one is choice (ID) and other one string (NID) but values are same. Requirement is to use only parameter either choice or string. Is it possible to convert choice parameter into string or string to choice parameter?
so that i can use one parameter and one deploy function.

```
def deploy1(env) {
step([$class: 'UCDeployPublisher',
siteName: siteName,
deploy: [
$class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.DeployHelper$DeployBlock',
deployApp: appName,
deployEnv: 'DEV',
deployVersions: "${compName}:${version}",
deployProc: simpleDeploy,
deployOnlyChanged: false,
deployReqProps: "ID=${params.ID}" ===> string paramater
]])

def deploy2(env) {
step([$class: 'UCDeployPublisher',
siteName: siteName,
deploy: [
$class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.DeployHelper$DeployBlock',
deployApp: appName,
deployEnv: 'DEV',
deployVersions: "${compName}:${version}",
deployProc: simpleDeploy,
deployOnlyChanged: false,
deployReqProps: "ID=${params.NID}"  ===> Needs choice paramater
]])

parameters {
choice(
name: 'ID',
choices: [ '8922', '9292', '3220' ]
 )

string(
name: 'NID',
defaultvalue: '8922,9292,3220'  
)

stage (DEV') {
steps {
    script {
     if (params.ENVIRONMENT == "dev"){
         deploy1('devl') ===> this will call my deploy function
      }
     }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can convert the string parameter to an array by just using `split`:
Below is an example :

```
// Define list which would contain all servers in an array
def ID= []
pipeline {
    agent none
     parameters
    {
        // Adding below as example string which is passed from paramters . this can be changed based on your need
        // Example: Pass NID list as , separated string in your project. This can be changed 
        string(name: 'NID', defaultValue:'8922,9292,3220', description: 'Enter , separated NID values in your project e.g. 8922,9292,3220')
    }
    stages {
        stage('DEV') {
            agent any
            steps {
                
                script
                {
                    // Update ID list
                    ID= params.NID.split(",")
                    // You can loop thorugh the ID list
                    for (myid in ID)
                    {
                        println ("ID is : ${myid}") 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```